# ApplicationService.State and tombstoning

Tags: windows-phone-7, serialization

Does ApplicationService.State get serialized to flash when an application is tombstoned? (WP7 and WP7.5)

Answer (score 0):

PhoneApplicationService.Current.State is where you would save your transient data in the case the application gets tombstoned.  You can then read this data back in and restore the state of your app.

Comment: this does not answer the question. The question is 'WHERE is this info serialized?'. What type of storage in other words...

Comment: Since this is only transient data and does not survive after reboot, I would think it would have to be in RAM.